# How to get WPF xaml content by code on form C#

Tags: wpf, xaml

I design a form in WPF project. The xaml content is automatically generated based on the GUI I design (drag/drop,set position on GUI). How can I read/retreive the xaml content data by code in C# on form?

Comment: just give a name to button etc. <Button x:Name="button1"/> and you can access button1.Content.or you mean something else?

Answer (score 1):

In WPF you have to decide what controls/UI elements are accessible in codebehind/C# by adding the Name="*someMeaningfullName*" or x:Name="*someMeaningfullName*" to the element in XAML.  Then you can access it in the codebehind like this: `someMeaningfullName.Text = "blablabla";`or similar.

The XAML:

```
<TextBox Name="_myTextBox" />
<!-- use x:Name if the element doesn't define the Name attribute -->
```

The codebehind:

```
string answer = _myTextBox.Text;
myTextBox.Text = "";
```

(By default, XAML elements are not represented by a member variable/field, as they would be in Windows Forms or ASP.NET)

Answer (score 0):

If you got your XAML content in a stream you can use XAMLReader like bellow
XamlReader.Load(stream) as UIElement

Update : Looks like you are looking to get the control reference to the code behind? Just name it with x:Name and use that inside your C# file.